# IllegalAccessError while using Javassist to edit JFrame Class

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I am using Javassist to edit the `JFrame` class at runtime, (adding a new Constructor)

```
 ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
 pool.importPackage("javax.swing.TransferHandler$HasGetTransferHandler");
 CtClass jFrameClass= pool.get("javax.swing.JFrame");
 jFrameClass.addConstructor(CtNewConstructor.make(new CtClass[]{pool.get("java.lang.String"),CtClass.intType,CtClass.intType},new CtClass[0],"{this($1);setSize($2,$3);}",jframe));
 jFrameClass.toClass();
```

Unfortunately, this throws an `IllegalAccessError`,

> Exception in thread "main" javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.swing.JFrame cannot access its superinterface javax.swing.TransferHandler$HasGetTransferHandler
>           at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1120)
>           at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1063)
>           at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1021)
>           at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1259)
>           at io.github.potatophil.PSStart.compile(PSStart.java:46)
>           at io.github.potatophil.PSStart.main(PSStart.java:24)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.swing.JFrame cannot access its superinterface javax.swing.TransferHandler$HasGetTransferHandler
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1133)
>           at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1114)
>           ... 10 more

I have tried using `pool.importPackage()`, to no avail.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It’s like trying to open a tiny door with a bulldozer—while the door is already open. After adding that constructor, there will be no code invoking it, so you have to generate that code as well. So why not generating code which simply uses an existing constructor, followed by a `setSize(…)` on the frame? What do you think is the advantage of that constructor, besides making you code inefficient and unmaintainable at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are encountering is related to the runtime definition of package-private packages.

Javassist cannot inject classes into the bootstrap class loader which is responsible for Swing. Instead, it will inject the altered class it into the system class path. This loaded class inherits from a package-private class which is however loaded "naturally" by the bootstrap class loader. By definition, this package is a different runtime package and can therefore not be accessed by its implementing class, causing the illegal access error.

Comment: I just want to say thank you so much. I ran into this issue locally and declaring my interface I was trying to proxy public made it work.